# Split string by number and character in php

Tags: php

I've seen some question about this problem but unfortunatly cant find my solution.

I have below string

```
$s = "ab2|5ac114|25ad"
```

I want get below result. An array has three member

```
{"ab","ac","ad"}
```

Seen 
[Link 1](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjADahUKEwiMtrCH-djGAhWEvBQKHe0iAB0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4311156%2Fhow-to-separate-letters-and-digits-from-a-string-in-php&ei=cx-kVcywLoT5Uu3FgOgB&usg=AFQjCNEO2VQ-HB2xbRV0Ep-tVx2EzCVllA&sig2=ZO0RGZlBoo4WHjZHBCqZww&bvm=bv.97653015,d.d24) [Link 3](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjABahUKEwiMtrCH-djGAhWEvBQKHe0iAB0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F14348018%2Fsplit-string-into-text-and-number&ei=cx-kVcywLoT5Uu3FgOgB&usg=AFQjCNHUSlsnThUoWSFsWy0fxsXPOIFz-A&sig2=fykO1YppQyn2AO7_LmAMag&bvm=bv.97653015,d.d24)

Comment: Show your effort. We are not providing a code writing service here.

Comment: I edited question update, please don't rate down

Comment: Seems you just need `explode`, since you've already seen those other questions.

Comment: `explode`, then `array_map` to apply a `preg_replace` on each resulting item.

Comment: I know to use use explode() but what expression should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP's [`preg_match_all()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) you can easily filter out only lower case alphabetical characters by `[a-z]` pattern. The quantifier `+` means any number between **one** and **unlimited**. But if you are always looking for 2 lowercase characters, then you can replace it with more specific quantifier like `{2}` so the pattern will be `"/[a-z]{2}/"`

```
<?php

$subject = 'ab2|5ac114|25ad';
preg_match_all("/[a-z]+/", $subject, $matches);
$result = $matches[0];

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you must search for such simple code for youself instead of asking first, you can use the following code:

```
$s = "ab2|5ac114|25ad";
$s = explode('|', $s);
for($i=0; $i<count($s); $i++)
{
    $s[$i] = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $s[$i]);
}
```

Here `preg_replace()` is uses regex to replace all characters not belonging from `a-z` with nothing, ie. it just removes them. `^` is used to indicate not belonging to. If you don't want to remove upper case characters then just add `A-Z` to the regex pattern, which will then become `/[^a-zA-Z]/`. If you are sure that `$s` will always contain nothing other than alphabets and numbers then you may also use `/[0-9]/`(notice that this doesn't contain `^`, so that only numbers are considered for replacement).